# Join list of function names into a series of nested function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a list of functions names `functions` stored as a string which I want to nest together to create an expression applied to some input string `var`:

```
f1,f2,f3
```

The end result would be this string:

```
f1(f2(f3({var})))
```

How could I go about doing that? I have this which gives what I want, wondering if it can be improved?

```
functions = 'f1,f2,f3'
var = 'hello'
all_functions = functions.split(',')
'('.join(all_functions) + '(' + var + ')'*len(all_functions)
```

Result

```
f1(f2(f3(hello)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```py
def nest(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    return f"{args[0]}({nest(*args[1:])})"
```

Example:

```py
>>> functions = "f1,f2,f3"
>>> var = "hello"
>>> nest(*functions.split(","), var)
'f1(f2(f3(hello)))'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split, saving you a line:

```
functions.replace(',', '(') + '(' + var + ')' * (functions.count(',') + 1)
```

You can also use string formatting, e.g., to ensure that `var` is converted to a string properly:

```
f'{functions.replace(",", "(")}({var}){")" * functions.count(",")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A way with `functools.reduce`:

```
reduce('{1}({0})'.format, functions.split(',')[::-1], var)
```

Answer (score -1):

A recursive function with parameter unpacking would do it elegantly:

```
def call(func,*params): 
    return f"{func}({call(*params)})" if params else func

functions = 'f1,f2,f3'
var = 'hello'

print(call(*functions.split(","),var))

f1(f2(f3(hello)))
```